# Swift 3 Show the 'Copy' popup on UITableViewCells when select cell of table like Contaccts app

Tags: ios, swift

How to show popup "copy" when select cell of table ?

[image]

Comment: Look into UIMenuController as that's what is being used to show that "pop up"

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it the normal way with `UILabel`. If you still want to do it, use `UITextField` instead and disable editing (It will act as label and allow text selection). If you want to use `UILabel` anyways, you might want to look into `UILongGestureRecognizer` and `UIPasteBoard`. Add gesture to the label and on its delegate method, copy text to paste board.